# User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/<AWS_USERNAME> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/role_name

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl

My company has given me a replacement laptop because the previous one has died. Using `aws configure`, I have configured AWS and also downloaded and added kubectl to the path. I have updated the kubectl config using

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig \
    --region us-west-2 \
    --name my-app-prd \
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/role_name
```

I changed the cluster using

```
kubectl config use-context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/my-app-prd
```

When I run

```
kubectl get svc
```

I get the following error message

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole
> operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/<AWS_USERNAME> is not
> authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource:
> arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/role_name E0201 09:59:49.896242    7160
> memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get
> "https://...eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials:
> exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254

Comment: Run the command `aws eks --region us-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name my-app-prd` and then run `kubectl get svc`. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command `aws eks --region us-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name my-app-prd`  to update the kubectl config and then run `kubectl get svc`